# Кодирование кириллических ссылок php. Вопрос?

Tags: php

Приветствую !

есть метки на сайте .Латинница обрабатывается как следует , а вот кириллица превращается в символы ...
`$this->base_url_page = $this->dir_http."/advmetka/".str_replace("%","_",RawUrlEncode($this->open_metka_value))."/";`

к примеру: **$this->base_url_page = евроремонт**,а выводит в адресной строке _D0_B5_D0_B2_D1_80_D0_BE_D1_80_D0_B5_D0_BC_D0_BE_D0_BD_D1_82

я так понимаю ,что любые кириллические символы всегда должны кодироваться в ссылках при переходе ..
А вот как изменить в адресной строке на читаемый вид и имеет ли это смысл?

Comment: А зачем вы меняете символы % на подчеркивания? Если не менять, то браузеры распознают кириллические символы и выводят читаемый урл в адресной строке.

Comment: я без понятия для чего это сделано было ..Это просто кусок кода движка ..Думал , может этому есть какое-то объяснение ,коль сделали